# mysql sum of tinyints

Tags: mysql, sql, tinyint

I have a table with five tinyint columns.

If I make a query searching for a row, I get a result like this:

```
select flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5 from mytable where whatever;
```

[Result set (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O8Uh.png)

[image]

What I need is to get the sum as if they were integers. In this example, the output are four ones and one zero, so I'd like to get a 4.

This query does not work:

```
select sum(flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5) from mytable where whatever;
```

This doesn't either:

```
select sum(flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4, flag5) from mytable where whatever;
```

Comment: What are you using for a database engine, SQL Server, MySQL? And can't you just CAST your tinyints to INT and sum them?

Comment: Why I get a -1? What's wrong with my question? Regards.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Now I see: MySQL (didn't know it was important)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `+` operator to sum up the values of a row.

```
SELECT flag1 + flag2 + flag3 + flag4 + flag5
       FROM mytable;
```

Comment: You probably want this sticky bit answer OR the mankowitz answer.  The point is that SUM() works across many rows of data.  The "+" adds numbers in the same row.

Comment: Make sure you test this scenario ..  255 + 255 + 255 + 255 + 255 so you can see if you are going to need to cast up to an int from tiny int.

Comment: Also Make sure you really didn’t want this …  flag1 | flag2 | flag3 | flag4 |flag5    aka. BITWISE OR   (mySql might be  “.|.”  for bitwise OR)

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(flag1 + flag2+ flag3+ flag4+ flag5) sumflag  from mytable
```

---

**Result:**

```
| sumflag |
|---------|
|       4 |
```

---

[Test Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb2ab3/3/0)

---

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (`flag1` tinyint, `flag2` tinyint, `flag3` tinyint, `flag4` tinyint, `flag5` tinyint)
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    (`flag1`, `flag2`, `flag3`, `flag4`, `flag5`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast `tinyint`s into `int`s to use `SUM()`. Try this:

```
select sum(cast (flag1 as int),cast (flag2 as int) ...
```

Comment: Besides, there's no need to cast. It happens by default.

Answer (score 1):

select sum(flag1+flag2+flag3+flag4+flag5 ) as total,id from mytable group by id